# how to enable --enable-experimental-mirrors in dart build?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors, dart2js

My build of my projects are failing because they rely on mirrors and dart build out put tells me to use `--enable-experimental-mirrors` to try to use mirrors in dart2js code as it is. so if I run `pub build --enable-experimental-mirrors` all I get is `Could not find an option named "enable-experimental-mirrors"`. Any hints much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself yet but maybe you can pass it as a command line option in the transformer config

```
transformers:
- $dart2js:
    commandLineOptions: [--enable-experimental-mirrors]
```

Comment: thanks, that stops the compiler warning about the experimental mirrors flag unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with the actual code though, https://github.com/0xor1/sandbox, that's my simple test code.

Comment: I have no information about the capabilities of this experimental mirrors support.